# Piston pushing on liquid to move another piston

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm trying to create a physics-based animation using two rigid pistons sliding inside a passive rigid body cylinder. The right cylinder pulls against a fluid geometry domain, which pushes against the left piston, causing it to slide to the left. I'd like to know if this is achievable with Blender, and if so, could you please give me some advice? I'm a Blender newbie who has been struggling with this issue for quite some time.

[image]

Comment: You'll never a physical accurate simulation, you can only fake the simulation, your fluid can also be fake instead of physic, it depends on your needs I guess.

Comment: Well, the purpose is not to get physically accurate results, but to simulate liquid-like behavior for the fluid domain - specifically, force transfer via compressibility (like a stiff spring I guess).

Comment: maybe show the different steps of the animation?

Comment: Yes, that will be the pure animation approach. I was just curious if there are any specific settings or procedures to follow in order to get physics-based animation.

Comment: it really depends on your story boards, could you please show the different steps of the animation?

Comment: To me it sounds like (since no physically accurate results are needed) as if you could simply animate this manually with keyframes...

Comment: i can only agree to Gordon and moonboots, just fake it until it looks good. So keyframe the piston and use fluid sim (Mantaflow or FlipFluid or whatever) in it if you want. Or even fake that...

Comment: @Chris I wouldn't even use any kind of simulation. What I see in the image is a fluid completely filling the space (as it should be in real life) so it can be done with a simple cylinder. The compression when one piston starts to push inwards can be faked by shortening the length of the cylinder accordingly.

Comment: also, is the liquid material supposed to be realistic?

Comment: Yes if you want something very simple just shapekey the water, or hook the left and right tip of the cylinder to some empties and move these empties